# Оставить только текст внутри нужных полей

Tags: регулярные-выражения, cmd, bat

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать следующую задачу:
Имеется большой файл следюущего содержания

```
define( 'name', 'Name1' );
random text
define( 'surname', 'Surname1' );
random text
define( 'password', '111111111' );
random text
define( 'api', '123123123123123123' );
random text
random text
define( 'name', 'Name2' );
random text
define( 'surname', 'Surname2' );
random text
define( 'password', '777777777777' );
random text
define( 'api', '90909090909090' );
```

На выходе нужно получить:

```
Name1;Surname1;111111111;123123123123123123
Name2;Surname2;777777777777;90909090909090
```

Как лучше это реализовать?

Comment: Я бы вместо батника взял какой-нибудь нормальный язык программирования. Или хотя бы PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

```
// regexp
define\( 'name', '([^']*?)' \);([\s\S]*?)define\( 'surname', '([^']*?)' \);([\s\S]*?)define\( 'password', '([^']*?)' \);([\s\S]*?)define\( 'api', '([^']*?)' \);

// replacement 
$1;$2;$3;$4 . "\n"
```

[пример](https://regex101.com/r/hhHRmL/2)

PS файл должен оканчиваться переводом строки!